# Data has been lost from a table in SQL database

Tags: sql-server

I made some changes in the stored procedure in test environment, while checking unfortunately i connected to production, i run the stored procedure. i lost the data in from one table. Is it possible to take back up of the data.
if possible kindly let me know.

Data base restore option in full.  Kindly suggest any tip to make data back to my table.

Answer (score 1):

since you are in Full recovery model,below is the approach that can be done to recover data..

1.Restore database with a different name till the time of delete
       a.)restore database with no recovery
        b.) restore each log till the point with no recovery and final one with    recovery
2.copy data from newdatabase  table to existing database table

Answer (score 0):

Once your table has been restored (and it sounds like you have backups, so that's good), put in place some technical restriction so the test environment can't connect to the production databases, so this can never happen again !